# Unstack columns in pandas-python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to Unpivot/unstack my dataframe. My df is like:

```
a=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Title','Status'],data=[['John','Course1','Finished'],['Mike','Course2','Accepted'],['Jim','Course1','Accepted'],['Jhonny','Course3','Rejected'],['Jhonny','Course3','Accepted']])
```

And I need it to be like:

[Excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRbF.png)

I have tried with pd.melt and pd.unstack() but not with the desired results. Can you give me a hand? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pivot_table()`

```
a.pivot_table(index='Name', columns=['Title'], values='Status', aggfunc='first')
```

prints:

```
         Course1   Course2   Course3
Name                                
Jhonny  Accepted       NaN  Rejected
Jim     Accepted       NaN       NaN
John    Finished       NaN       NaN
Mike         NaN  Accepted       NaN
```

I think you have a typo in your sample DF above. I think it should be:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Title','Status'], data=[['John','Course1','Finished'],['Mike','Course2','Accepted'],['Jim','Course1','Accepted'],['Jhonny','Course3','Rejected'],['Jhonny','Course1','Accepted']])
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know pivot_table worked with strings too. But what is the difference between 'first' and 'last' in this case?

Comment: ```first``` returns the first observation, while ```last``` returns the last observation. In your sample data, it shouldn't have a difference, both should yield the same outcome.